# Block ICMP unreachable outgoing packets

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking

I am trying out iptables rules to block following traffic; which is a response for unreachable host.

```
17:50:11.140992 IP 10.1.1.93 > 72.21.91.29: ICMP host 10.1.1.93 unreachable, length 48
17:50:11.140997 IP 10.1.1.93 > 72.21.91.29: ICMP host 10.1.1.93 unreachable, length 48
```

I added following rule

```
[admin@user ~]# iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3/1 -s 10.1.1.93 -j DROP
[admin@user ~]# iptables -nL 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
...
...
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  10.1.1.93            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3 code 1
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8              /* COMMENT */
```

Also tried blocking all icmp type 3 packets but somehow I still see the packets in tcpdump. Can someone help what I am doing wrong here?

```
[admin@user ~]# iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -s 10.1.1.93 -j DROP
```

Edit: Closest question I see is this one which does not have answer yet. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217750/undesired-icmp-destionation-unreachable-message

Comment: You really get `Destination Host Unreachable` for your own IP? Add more verbose output to tcpdump (`-vv`), maybe it is not your host which is answering. Therefore try also the `FORWARD` table.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz The host has multiple interfaces. The IP for which I get "Host Unreachable" is not assigned to any interface. It is updated as source IP through iptable SNAT rule. That is probably why the host does not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `10.1.1.93` is not the address of any interface and you have a SNAT rule, I would guess that the ICMP packet is generated with a different source address, so your `iptables` rule does not match.

To get rid of those `Destination Host Unreachable` packets you could add the correct address to the `iptables` rule or no address at all:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type host-unreachable -j DROP
```

However, I would work on their cause: someone tries to connect to an address that can appear only on outgoing, not incoming connections. A rule like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.1.1.93 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

should solve your problem. Remark: it is in the `FORWARD` table, since those connections will not reach into `INPUT`.